# No Module Called "BeautifulSoup"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python3 and have downloaded BeautifulSoup on my Mac, but it keeps showing "there's no module named bs4" or "there's no module named BeautifulSoup". What should I do?

This is a homework from Py4E of Web Scraping on Coursera.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

> There is no module named bs4

```
$pip install BeautifulSoup
```

> Invalid syntax

```
import BeautifulSoup from BeautifulSoup
```

> There is no module named BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 5):

First [install BeautifuleSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download)  with:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And then import in your Python file like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 1):

First install it by:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then,you should import it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

You can also check it's installation by and see the package name there:

```
pip freeze
```

Comment: It shows "can't read /var/mail/bs4" but I did install BeautifulSoup. What should I do then? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> `$pip install BeautifulSoup`
>
> Invalid syntax

This is not Python code. The line `pip install BeautifulSoup` is something you type **at the command line**, not in your code. (The `$` is an indicator, in the example you were looking at, that this is a command for the command line - it's commonly used for Unix-like shells.)

Comment: Thank you, man! Sorry for the mistake, but that's because I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't know the correct format yet. However, I've found how to solve this question: in the terminal, input "pip3 install bs4" and then import bs4, then we can import beautifulsoup4. Anyway, thank you so much!